# Using client certificate with python requests

Tags: c#, python, rest, ssl-certificate, python-requests

I would like to use a client certificate for the authentification at my REST-Service. After testing the configuration with my generated certificates in Firefox I would say, that my configuration is right, since the authentification at my service works as desired.
Now, I have to implement this certificate into my python-script. I'm using python-requests:

```
rsp = requests.put(url='{0}recorditems/{1}'.format(daemonConfig['service']['url'], recorditemOID)
, data=body, headers=headers
, cert=daemonConfig['daemon']['certPath'], verify=False)
```

But when I send a requests via this method and start debugging in Visual Studio, the object Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate has the length 0; no certificate is included.
The certificate exists definitely at the location specified in my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the path to the certificate that should be passed to `verify` not `cert`. `cert` accepts a tuple. Also by setting `verify=False` you're telling requests to ignore the `cert` parameter altogether.